# Apache Hadoop 2.7.4, configuring Fair Scheduler cause error

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have configured a Hadoop 2.7.4 cluster with 3 workers and one master. I have to run multiple jobs on cluster. One job takes a lot of time to complete while other are small jobs. I have come to know that Fair Scheduler is best for my case. When I updated yarn-site.xml [Fair Scheduler class](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html) and restart cluster, it cause following error when I access http://localhost:8088/cluster ( resource manager web UI )

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /cluster/. Reason:

    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.QueueMetrics.getReservedMB()J
Caused by:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.QueueMetrics.getReservedMB()J
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.dao.UserMetricsInfo.<init>(UserMetricsInfo.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.MetricsOverviewTable.render(MetricsOverviewTable.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.render(HtmlBlock.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.renderPartial(HtmlBlock.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.View.render(View.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock$Block.subView(HtmlBlock.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet.Hamlet._(Hamlet.java:30347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.AppsBlockWithMetrics.render(AppsBlockWithMetrics.java:29)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.render(HtmlBlock.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.renderPartial(HtmlBlock.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.View.render(View.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage$Page.subView(HtmlPage.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet.HamletImpl$EImp._v(HamletImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet.Hamlet$TD._(Hamlet.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.TwoColumnLayout.render(TwoColumnLayout.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage.render(HtmlPage.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.render(Dispatcher.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:167)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:900)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebAppFilter.doFilter(RMWebAppFilter.java:172)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:795)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter.doFilter(StaticUserWebFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RMAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer2.java:1263)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: if you haven't yet then go through `hadoop classpath`? make sure correct version of `hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager` jar present in hadoop  classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in 2.7.4 version that has been fixed in 2.7.5!
[JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-5402)